# Make an android app work on both Android watch and Android phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I've written an android app in Android studio, and would like to add android wear functionality. I've looked into it online, but I can only find help on how to make a stand-alone android wear app. Is it not possible for me to just add a new activity to the application that is used by the smart watch, or do I have to create a whole new app for the smart watch that requests data from the main phone application?

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what it is you need the wear app to do?

In the past I have decided all I actually needed was the ability to respond to notifications on the watch so therefore I just modified the notifications to work well on android wear.

Example. https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

But if for example you need the ability to start the app from the watch and work without any phone interaction, you will need to create a stand alone android wear module.